# Bulk download or Web service offering brand logos

Tags: logo, workflow

I have a rather long list of global brands (about 2000) for which I would like to download a brand logo. I was wondering if there is a way to automate this process, since I know that this list will get longer in the future.

I am thinking about something along the lines of a Web service that I could call to get the logo of a given brand, or at least a large archive of logos that I can download.

So far the only solution I have found involves manually searching for each brand on one of the sites hosting brand logos: brandsoftheworld.com, logotypes101.com, gmkfreelogos.com. But none of them provide any form of "bulk download" option.

Comment: The problem you are going to have is to specify what logos as there is no naming convention and those sites offer sometimes multiple versions. I guess depending on the project it could be an option to mail all the companies for their logos. But that really only works if you have a business relationship with them.

Comment: There are a few sites out there that do just this...archive global logos in vector formats. Alas, I can't recall a URL off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

BrandsOfTheWorld.com has a large collection of vector logos.

EDIT
Just saw your additional details. There is no way to do a bulk download. That's probably a good thing (;

Answer (score 0):

It's a nice tool to search and download the site's content. The only thing you need is to properly configure it.

http://www.httrack.com/html/faq.html#Q13

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) would be a great place to start for this. It may cost a little more but you'd get quality results.